# Deploying an application to a Linux server on Google compute engine

Tags: linux, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

My developer has written a web scraping app on Linux on his private machine, and asked me to provide him with a Linux server. I setup an account on Google Compute Engine, created a Linux image with enough resources and a sufficiently large SSD drive. Three weeks later he is claiming that working on Google is too complex quote - "google is complex because their deployment process is separate for all modules. especially i will have to learn about how to set a scheduler and call remote scripts (it looks they handle these their own way)."

He suggests I create an account on Hostgator.com.

I appreciate that I am non-technical, but I cannot be that difficult to use Linux on Google?! Am I missing something? Is there any advice you could give me?

Comment: GCE instance is just simple VM.
I think u can let ur developer to use more simple connection and deployment like scp. There are no difference between GCE and other cloud. It is just linux box which can accessed by using SSH.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the suggestion to create an account on Hostgator to utilize what I presume would be a [VPS](http://www.hostgator.com/vps-hosting) in lieu of a Virtual Machine on [GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) , I would suggest seeking a more concrete example from the developer.

For instance, the comment about the "scheduler", let's refer to it as some process that needs to execute on a regular basis:

1. How is this 'process' currently accomplished on the private machine ?
2. How would it be done on the VPS ?
3. What is preventing this 'process' from being done on the GCE VM ?

Comment: Ok thanks. I will raise this with him in the morning. Thanks